# How to find the pandas record with positive value closest to zero?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the pandas record where the value is closest to zero AND positive.

Here is a small sample of the data:

```
                 Date  Budget
0 2018-02-24 11:20:16    6.35
1 2018-02-24 11:34:10    5.85
2 2018-02-24 16:41:12    3.85
3 2018-02-25 00:55:18    1.10
4 2018-02-25 01:36:47   -0.90
5 2018-02-25 03:12:51   -1.90
6 2018-02-25 11:29:31   -2.90
7 2018-02-25 18:20:35   -3.65
```

The closest I got was using a SO answer:

```
near_zero = df['Budget'].abs().min()
```

That returns only the value and not the record plus the value is a converted negative value. (index[4])
I need a search pattern that will for this sample, return both column values index[3], the lowest positive value of 'Budget'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter positive values and then get `min`:

```
near_zero = df.loc[df['Budget'] > 0, 'Budget'].min()
print (near_zero)
1.1
```

and then if possible multiple mins:

```
df1 = df[df['Budget'] == near_zero]
print (df1)

                 Date  Budget
3 2018-02-25 00:55:18     1.1
```

Or if only one minimal value, thanks @coldspeed:

```
df1 = df.loc[[df.loc[df['Budget'] > 0, 'Budget'].idxmin()]]
print (df1)

                 Date  Budget
3 2018-02-25 00:55:18     1.1
```

Comment: that's cool but how do I also get the  "Date" value for that record?

Comment: @TimothyLombard `df.loc[df.loc[df['Budget'] > 0, 'Budget'].idxmin()]`

Comment: With some minor tweaks, we can find the largest negative record closest to zero!   neg_df = df.loc[[df.loc[df['Budget'] < 0, 'Budget'].idxmax()]]

Answer (score 1):

Or try using [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
near_zero=df['Budget'].clip(lower=0).replace(0,np.inf).min()
```

Or [`clip_lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html):

```
near_zero=df['Budget'].clip_lower(0).replace(0,np.inf).min()
```

And both cases:

```
print(near_zero)
```

Is:

```
1.1
```

Comment: Check this again, please. I get 6.35 only.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the correct value:

```
near_zero = df[df['Budget'] > 0].min()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another similar but interesting solution with clip function

```
near_zero=df['Budget'].clip(lower=0).replace(0,df['Budget'].max()).min()
```

It is basically replacing the values less than 0 to the maximum value in the list.